# Removing a node from Galera Cluster

Tags: mysql, galera, percona-xtradb-cluster

I have to update the os on a few servers and I need to remove a db from the cluster.

```
wsrep_cluster_address='gcomm://192.168.2.59,192.168.2.60,192.168.2.61,192.168.2.62,192.168.2.63'
```

Do I remove the ip adress from the cluster line then restart each node?
Or do I stop the service on the server I want to remove from the cluster then remove the ip address on the other nodes then restart the mysql service?

Comment: In general you do both: you stop the node to be removed, and then remove it from configurations of other nodes, where it is mentioned. However, this is not required nor recommended for an update. Had you read Galera update instructions?

Comment: No I have not read the update instructions. I couldn't find any instructions.  My issue is i am moving from mysql 5.7 to 8.0.  My plan was update on server get galera working then update another server.  Can you post the link.

Comment: dba.stackexchange is a better place for DBA questions about may database.